# Image quality reduced after saving bitmap to SD card

Tags: java, android, image

I am using an activity to display a Full image and user has a button to save it.

Image is being loaded in imageview from URL where I have hosted image on internet.

I am saving an image as PNG file.

After saving image its quality is reduced. I know PNG is not lossless, but is there any way I can save an image as it is without any compromise with quality or resolution??

Here is the code:

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        fullSizeImage.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm=fullSizeImage.getDrawingCache();
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + File.separator + "MyWallpapers");
        if(!myDir.exists())
        {
            myDir.mkdir();
        }
        String fname = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())+".png";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        /*if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); */
        try 
        {
            //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            /*FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);*/

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

            file.createNewFile();
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            bytes.flush();
            bytes.close();
            /*out.flush();
            out.close();*/
            Toast.makeText(FullSizeImageDisplay.this, "Wallpaper Saved in SDcard/MyWallpapers folder",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String[] paths = {root + File.separator + "MyWallpapers"};

            String[] mediaType = {"image/png"};
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(FullSizeImageDisplay.this, paths, mediaType, null);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png"); 

            getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        Uri outputFileUri;

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fullSizeImage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=fullSizeImage.getDrawingCache();
```

Where fullSizeImage is may be an Image View.

I see problem is arising while you load the image. You must have used something like  BitmapFactory.Options

Make following changes

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(<param1>,param2,null);
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(<param1>,param2,null); is replacement for what?

Comment: Are doing any lazy loading kind of thing ? Or decoding url to bmp for just once image ?

Comment: decoding url to bmp for one image.

Comment: I think in my imageview image is loaded properly with its quality. There is another button in the activity to set this imageview's image as wallpaper. When I set an image directly as wallpaper its set as high quality image. The problem is when I save to SD card its quality is reduced

Comment: Why you are using getDrawingCache() method. After decoding it from the url you must be having one bmp. Use that bmp to save it to SD Card. getDrawingCache() is unnecessary step.